# How to Extends a Pug file in laravel project

Tags: laravel, pug

Hi guys I'm using a laravel Package it help me to use Pug template engine in my laravel project 
the package link : https://github.com/BKWLD/laravel-pug

I have some issues

**Folder Structurs**

```
- Views 
  - Frontend (
      - layouts (
          index.pug
      )
  )
- master.pug
```

I want extends the **master.pug** to **index.pug** please help

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the pug documentation for [includes](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html)

All you need to do is this at the top of your master.pug file:

```
include layouts/index.pug
```